# How can I execute more than one command in exec command of linux expect

Tags: linux, bash, shell, networking, expect

I'm trying to detect a host is available by using expect of Linux.

Now, I can using the following commands via bash to get the return value and check host status.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
nc -z $DUT_IP 22 && echo $?
```

I want to do the same things via expect. But seems I failed.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --   
set DUT_IP "192.168.1.9"
set result [exec nc -z $DUT_IP 22] 
send_user "$result\n\n"
```

I got the following error messages:

```
    invalid port &&
        while executing
    "exec nc -z $DUT_IP 22 && echo $?"
        invoked from within
    "set result [exec nc -z $DUT_IP 22 && echo $?] "
        (file "reboot.exp" line 44)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of `&&` to separate commands is a shell construct, not an expect construct. You can explicitly launch a shell for that command list:

```
set result [exec sh -c "nc -z $DUT_IP 22 && echo $?"]
```

Note that will only print the exit status if the command **succeeded**, thus result will either be "0" or empty. You want to use `;` instead of `&&`

Comment: Very thanks for your kindly reply. It is useful for me.